# Angular ng-intl-tel-input binding phone number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a third party plugin, [ng-intl-tel-input](https://github.com/hodgepodgers/ng-intl-tel-input) for a phone input form.  I'm having two issues that I haven't found an answer for yet and hoping to get some insight.  I'm  following the author's instruction almost exactly with the exception of changing the ng-model to an existing model.

The first issue is that the model that I've specified for the ng-model doesn't get updated with the phone number I enter.  In my case below, `user.phone` shows as undefined.

```
<div class="field-holder">
    <input  type = "text"
            name = "phone"
            placeholder = "Enter Phone #"
            class = "form-control"
            ng-model = "user.phone"
            required-message="'Please provide phone no.'"
            required
            ng-intl-tel-input/>
</div>
```

The second issue is that I'm getting a validation error with valid phone numbers I'm testing out.  Is there something I need to update/change in the plugin source code?

Apologies if this is redundant and if there's already an answer out there!  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried specifiy `data-initial-country` attribute to something you want? Perhaps this is what is causing the validation error. **Note:** Validation errors will NOT update your model, that's the reason your `user.phone` doesn't get updated. Also, try removing `required` if previous suggestion didn't work. Sometimes this directive already validates.